# Is 爱 limited to people?

Tags: usage

[What's the meaning of the first part of: 他爱怎么想就怎么想，我才不在乎呢](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/21456/whats-the-meaning-of-the-first-part-of-%E4%BB%96%E7%88%B1%E6%80%8E%E4%B9%88%E6%83%B3%E5%B0%B1%E6%80%8E%E4%B9%88%E6%83%B3-%E6%88%91%E6%89%8D%E4%B8%8D%E5%9C%A8%E4%B9%8E%E5%91%A2)

and

[Is "我爱辣" (Wǒ ài là) a correct/understandable/idiomatic way of saying I like my food spicy?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/5575/is-%E6%88%91%E7%88%B1%E8%BE%A3-w%C7%92-%C3%A0i-l%C3%A0-a-correct-understandable-idiomatic-way-of-saying-i-like-my-f)

suggest that 爱 can be used for things and abstractions, but that it may not be idiomatic.

Would it be common, sometimes, or never for pets?  Other animals?  Hobbies?  etc.

Comment: No limitations - go wild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is my first answer on this website.

他爱怎么想就怎么想,我才不在乎呢  = whatever he thinks/would like to think, I don't care.
In this sentence, 爱 is generally can be understanded as "would like". 
I prefer to say 我爱吃辣(I love eating spicy food) insted of 我爱辣
If you just only say 我爱辣, people may get confused when they hear this.

爱 can be used for things/hobbies etc, but a verb often followed by 爱。Examples: I love sports = 我爱运动。 I love playing basketball =我爱打篮球。 I love playing games = 我爱玩游戏。

Sometimes, you can use 爱 for pets and animals. However, I prefer to say 喜欢. Examples: 我喜欢动物。我喜欢小狗。 我喜欢小猫。

Comment: That is helpful.  谢谢

Comment: Do others agree with my assessment that 爱 followed by an activity, or hobby, is not as strong as 爱 used for people? That is to say, there is a bigger difference between: 我爱你 and 我喜欢你 than there is between 我爱打篮球 and 我喜欢打篮球？